# trying to find a solution for my undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, pdo

I have a table with a list of categories and I also have a form to search for the title of categories.

And Im getting this working like I want but Im having *two notices* that Im not able to find a solution already for a few days.

I know if I put @ before the sql statments I solve my problem, but I think that´s not correct.

The search form is working fine when I pass a value, but When I dont pass any value I always have the notice saying: "Notice: Undefined index: where", because the select to load the list of categories is done without having been passed any value to my `$_SESSION['where']` that is used in my sql statement.

Somebody there see some solution to solve this notices?

Im having this errors:

**Notice:** Undefined index: where in my "SELECT * FROM categories {$_SESSION['where']}..."

And I know that Im having this errors because

**My php code** for store in session the sql statment that the user pass in my search field:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
{
$search = $_POST['search'];
if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Search...:')
{
    $_SESSION['where'] = "WHERE t LIKE '%$search%'";
    header('Location: index2.php?exe=posts/categories');
}
else
{
    unset($_SESSION['where']);
    header('Location: index2.php?exe=posts/categories');
}
}
```

Then I do my sql statment:

**My php code for sql statment:**

```
$pag = (empty($_GET['pag']) ? '1' : $_GET['pag']);
$max = 3; 
$begin = ($pag * $max) - $max;

$readCategory = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories {$_SESSION['where']} ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT :begin, :max");
$readCategory->bindParam(':begin', $begin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readCategory->bindParam(':max', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readCategory->execute();



$num_readCategory = $readCategory->rowCount();

if(!$num_readCategory >= 1)
{
echo 'There are not categories yet';
}
```

Comment: `session_start();` loaded? Plus, why do I feel like I've seen this question/code before?

Comment: sql in the session... ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve the problem exactly as you did with the $_GET parameter:

```
$where = isset($_SESSION['where']) ? $_SESSION['where'] : '';
$readCategory = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories {$where} ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT :begin, :max");
```

Also, I usually encapsulate such access in a function/method:

```
function get_session_param($name, $default = null) {
   if (isset($_SESSION[ $name ])) {
       return $_SESSION[ $name ]; 
   }
   return $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your search term is empty you're unsetting the `$_SESSION['where']` variable, hence it's undefined.

Instead, just set it to an empty string:

```
else
{
    $_SESSION['where'] = "";
    header('Location: index2.php?exe=posts/categories');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...it makes sense, but I got the same error!